# Angularjs: go next page button fetch from api

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have api url : "api/books/01/text?page=0".

It has json format:

```
{ "content":" This is page one. " , "pageInfo" : {"count": 6, "id": "0"} }
```

I have no problem fetch data on the view:

```
.factory('Service',function($http) {
  return {
    url: '.../api/books/01/text?page=0',

    fetch: function(config) {
      return $http.get(this.url, config).then(function(json) {
        return json.data;
      });
    },
  }
```

But Suppose I want to make button that go to next page when user click on next button, the view will change the text base on the information that next api url "api/books/01/text?page=1", what should I do?

Comment: do you want to retain the page number or not? i.e. if the user clicks "next" a couple times and then refreshes the page, it's ok if everything will start again from page 0?

Comment: You just need to update your model, and display that model element in your view.

Comment: No, I don't want to retain the page, when the user refreshes the page, it should stay on current page.

Comment: @guilhebl Is there example ?

Comment: let me post in an answer what I think you're looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposing your page.id is your page index and page.count is the count of number of elements on that page, in your controller code:

```
$scope.page = Service.fetch($scope.config);
```

in your HTML:

```
<div>
<span>Page: {{page.id}}</span>
<span>Records: {{page.count}}</span>
<button ng-disabled="{{page.id === 0}}" ng-click="nextPage()"> Next</button>
</div>
```

Controller function handler for button click

```
  // fetch next page
$scope.nextPage = function() {
    $scope.config.pageIndex = scope.config.pageIndex + 1;
    $scope.page = Service.fetch($scope.config);
 };
```

Comment: Thanks you for your help, I get it.